# Is it possibile to call @RequestMapping under @Scheduled in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, scheduled-tasks

I am new in Spring MVC. I have to call an *@RequestMapping* with interval of 15 minutes. So can I call *@RequestMapping* under *@Scheduled(fixedRate = 30000)* ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you can use `httpClient` to simulate a http request

Answer (score 1):

Need to add spring notations to use scheduler, also this is independent if you use to create a service. In most cases the libraries or notations of spring allow working between them. Regarding your query you will need to have a configuration file in which you will add the notation

```
 @Configuration
 @ComponentScan ({"com.example.demo"}) 
 @EnableScheduling
 public class SpringWebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {...}
```

Then in your controller class add methods with the notation @Scheduled (initialDelay = 1000)
for planning how much time. Besides these there are other parameters like cron, initialDelay

this is a simple example

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping ("/")
public class DemoController {
   @RequestMapping (value = "demo", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String printWelcome (ModelMap model) {
      model.addAttribute ("message", "Hello world!");
      return "hello";
}

@Scheduled (fixedRate = 5000)
public void ScheduledFixedRate () {
    System.out.println ("I will execute after evey 5 seconds");
}
```

Previously, use this link in order to understand the configuration of Scheduling:
https://javadeveloperzone.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-cron-scheduler/